# Having an issue with rendering table in a React component

Tags: reactjs, render

I am trying to render a table inside a react component but having trouble aligning the rows with the header

```
render() {
         console.log("Top Searches",this.props.topSearches)
         return(
          <div className="topsearches">
          <table border="2" align="center">
          <th> Search Term </th>
          <th>Count </th>
             {this.props.topSearches.map((top_search, index) => (
                  <tr>
                    {Object.keys(top_search).map(function(key) {
                      return <div>      
                      <tbody>
                      <td align="center">{key} </td>
                      <td align="right">{top_search[key]}</td>
                      </tbody>
                       </div>

                      })}


                </tr>
            ))}
            </table>
          </div>

      )
    }
```

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpSQ4.png) is the output i am getting

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I assume, you are trying to achieve something like this.

I have edited this in codesandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/sparkling-sound-yd1ih).
https://codesandbox.io/s/sparkling-sound-yd1ih

```
return (
    <div className="topsearches">
      <table border="2" align="center">
        <thead>
          <th> Search Term </th>
          <th>Count </th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {props.topSearches.map((top_search, index) =>
            Object.keys(top_search).map((key, index) => {
              return (
                <tr>
                  <td>{key}</td>
                  <td>{top_search[key]}</td>
                </tr>
              );
            })
          )}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
```

Modification I made to achieve this:

- Added `<thead>`
- Corrected `<tbody>` loop

Please let me know if you have any further questions!

Comment: One issie I have is my json has only one object so

Comment: so [{"apple": 42, iphone:10} instead of [ {apple:42}, {iphone:10}]

Comment: So will it display only one value in a row ?
Do you want to display only one value in a row ?

Comment: yes i want it displaye dthe way u have it but having difficulty ding that

Comment: please provide your JSON input data

Comment: This is my JSON output

Comment: [
    {
        "Apple iPhone 6 32GB": 50,
        "iPhone": 1
    }
]

Comment: I have updated codesandbox

Please check and let me know.